# Why is my program saying there is an error: "interface expected here"?

Tags: java

Whenever I type this code, java always underlines the class declaration sentence and the error message is "interface expected here". How can I fix this?

```
package tempconverter;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import static java.lang.System.out;
public class TempConverter extends JFrame implements ActionListener, ActionEvent{
        static JFrame f = new JFrame();
        static JTextField enter = new JTextField(3);
        static JButton confirm = new JButton("Convert");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        f.setSize(100, 50);
        f.pack();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(enter); 
        f.add(confirm);
        f.setVisible(true);

    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        double toConvert = Float.parseFloat(enter.getText());
        double inF, inK;
        inF = toConvert / 5 * 9 + 32;
        inK = toConvert + 273;
        out.println("In degrees Fahrenheit, " + toConvert + "degrees Celsius would be " +         inF   + "degrees.");
        out.println("In degrees Kelvin, " + toConvert + "degrees Celsius would be " + inK     + "degrees.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to implement a class

`ActionEvent` is a class not interface.

And in your program you don't need to extend `TempConverter` with `JFrame`

Hence you can use it as :

```
public class TempConverter extends ActionEvent implements ActionListener
```

and to extend `ActionEvent` you will need to create a Cunstructor of TempConverter because `ActionEvent` is containing a public cunstructor in it.

Answer (score 3):

As per the [Java Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html), `ActionEvent` is a `class`. You can only implement `interfaces`, hence the very clear error message.

**What I think you meant..**

Normally, when I want to implement some custom `ActionListener`, I take a similar approach:

```
public class MyAction implements ActionListener {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         // Your code here.
     }
}
```

There is no need to take on the methods in `ActionEvent`. `ActionEvent` is passed in when the event is called. By doing this, you can then access `MyAction` as follows:

```
JButton button = new JButton("Click me!");
button.addActionListener(new MyAction());
```

And whatever code you put into the `actionPerformed` method, will be called on button click.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `ActionEvent` is not an interface but you wrote `implements ActionEvent`. Java compiler expects interface name after keyword `implements` and this is what it says.

In your case just remove `ActionEvent`. You do not need it at all.

Answer (score 0):

You are `implements` an Abstract While you have to `extends` it